# Issue with order of loading multiple csv files using list.files()

Tags: r, csv, file

I am trying to load a long list of csv files, names spec_cap1, spec_cap2 ..., spec_cap77. In my directory, they are in the correct order. I'm currently trying to use

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
files

combined_files <- bind_rows(lapply(files, fread))
combined_files
```

When I do this, I get the files but they are out of order - R reads spec_cap1, then spec_cap10, spec_cap11 etc, and then spec_cap2, spec_cap21.

I tried specifying the exact files using:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "spec_cap[1-77].csv")
files

combined_files <- bind_rows(lapply(files, fread))
combined_files
```

But I ran into the same problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, the file names are sorted by their string value, not by the numerical part. Does the order in which they are read make any difference for what you want to do? If you use `combined_files <- readr::read_csv(files, id = "path")` instead, you'll get a column with the file path which you can use as an identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your file names first and then read them in:

```r
files <- c("spec_cap1", "spec_cap10", "spec_cap11", "spec_cap2", "spec_cap21")
files <- stringr::str_sort(files, numeric = TRUE)
# [1] "spec_cap1"  "spec_cap2"  "spec_cap10" "spec_cap11" "spec_cap21"
```

`str_sort` from the package `stringr` will sort the numeric values rather than the string values when `numeric = TRUE`